# Create Kind cluster inside vscode devcontainer fails after a delete

Tags: windows, docker, vscode-devcontainer, kind

I am trying to create a kind cluster in a vscode devcontainer. I am working on windows with docker desktop and have been using a docker inside docker template.

When the container is first constructed I am able to create a cluster using `kind create cluster`  from a terminal within the container and this works successful
However if i delete the cluster and try to create again it fails. This does not happen when I do this from the host windows machine, it will create every time, only from within the container.

The output:

```
Creating cluster "kind" ... DEBUG: docker/images.go:58] Image: kindest/node:v1.27.3@sha256:3966ac761ae0136263ffdb6cfd4db23ef8a83cba8a463690e98317add2c9ba72 present locally  ✓ Ensuring node image (kindest/node:v1.27.3)   ✓ Preparing nodes    DEBUG: config/config.go:96] Using the following kubeadm config for node kind-control-plane: apiServer:   certSANs:
      - localhost
      - 127.0.0.1   extraArgs:
        runtime-config: "" apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3 clusterName: kind controlPlaneEndpoint: kind-control-plane:6443 controllerManager:  extraArgs:
        enable-hostpath-provisioner: "true" kind: ClusterConfiguration kubernetesVersion: v1.27.3 networking:   podSubnet: 10.244.0.0/16   serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/16 scheduler:   extraArgs: null
    --- apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3 bootstrapTokens:
    - token: abcdef.0123456789abcdef kind: InitConfiguration localAPIEndpoint:   advertiseAddress: 172.19.0.2   bindPort: 6443 nodeRegistration:   criSocket: unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  kubeletExtraArgs:
        node-ip: 172.19.0.2
        node-labels: ""
        provider-id: kind://docker/kind/kind-control-plane
    --- apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3 controlPlane:   localAPIEndpoint:
        advertiseAddress: 172.19.0.2
        bindPort: 6443 discovery:   bootstrapToken:
        apiServerEndpoint: kind-control-plane:6443
        token: abcdef.0123456789abcdef
        unsafeSkipCAVerification: true kind: JoinConfiguration nodeRegistration:   criSocket: unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  kubeletExtraArgs:
        node-ip: 172.19.0.2
        node-labels: ""
        provider-id: kind://docker/kind/kind-control-plane
    --- apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1 cgroupDriver: systemd cgroupRoot: /kubelet evictionHard:   imagefs.available: 0%   nodefs.available: 0%   nodefs.inodesFree: 0% failSwapOn: false imageGCHighThresholdPercent: 100 kind: KubeletConfiguration
    --- apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1 conntrack:   maxPerCore: 0 iptables:   minSyncPeriod: 1s kind: KubeProxyConfiguration mode: iptables  ✓ Writing configuration   DEBUG: kubeadminit/init.go:82] I0919 16:04:50.065023     197 initconfiguration.go:255] loading configuration from "/kind/kubeadm.conf" W0919 16:04:50.065940     197 initconfiguration.go:332] [config] WARNING: Ignored YAML document with GroupVersionKind kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3, Kind=JoinConfiguration [init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.27.3 I0919 16:04:50.072300     197 certs.go:112] creating a new certificate authority for ca [certs] Using certificateDir folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki" [certs] Generating "ca" certificate and key I0919 16:04:50.164763     197 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for ca certificate [certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key [certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [kind-control-plane kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local localhost] and IPs [10.96.0.1 172.19.0.2 127.0.0.1] [certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key I0919 16:04:50.423042   197 certs.go:112] creating a new certificate authority for front-proxy-ca [certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key I0919 16:04:50.925744     197 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for front-proxy-ca certificate [certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key I0919 16:04:51.241200     197 certs.go:112] creating a new certificate authority for etcd-ca [certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key I0919 16:04:51.475406     197 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for etcd/ca certificate [certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key [certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [kind-control-plane localhost] and IPs [172.19.0.2 127.0.0.1 ::1] [certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key [certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [kind-control-plane localhost] and IPs [172.19.0.2 127.0.0.1 ::1] [certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key [certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key I0919 16:04:51.926244     197 certs.go:78] creating new public/private key files for signing service account users [certs] Generating "sa" key and public key [kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes" I0919 16:04:52.222532     197 kubeconfig.go:103] creating kubeconfig file for admin.conf [kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file I0919 16:04:52.544088     197 kubeconfig.go:103] creating kubeconfig file for kubelet.conf [kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file I0919 16:04:52.836036     197 kubeconfig.go:103] creating kubeconfig file for controller-manager.conf [kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file I0919 16:04:53.045704     197 kubeconfig.go:103] creating kubeconfig file for scheduler.conf [kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file I0919 16:04:53.349922     197 kubelet.go:67] Stopping the kubelet [kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env" [kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml" [kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet [control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests" [control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver" I0919 16:04:53.461569     197 manifests.go:99] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs I0919 16:04:53.462096     197 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for CA certificate I0919 16:04:53.462199     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "ca-certs" for component "kube-apiserver" I0919 16:04:53.462205     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "etc-ca-certificates" for component "kube-apiserver" I0919 16:04:53.462209     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "k8s-certs" for component "kube-apiserver" I0919 16:04:53.462213     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-local-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-apiserver" I0919 16:04:53.462216     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-apiserver" I0919 16:04:53.465579     197 manifests.go:154] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-apiserver" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml" I0919 16:04:53.465626  197 manifests.go:99] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs [control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.465817     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "ca-certs" for component "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.465851     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "etc-ca-certificates" for component "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.465859     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "flexvolume-dir" for component "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.465865     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "k8s-certs" for component "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.465871     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "kubeconfig" for component "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.465877     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-local-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.465883     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.466516     197 manifests.go:154] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-controller-manager" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml" I0919 16:04:53.466555     197 manifests.go:99] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs I0919 16:04:53.466714     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "kubeconfig" for component "kube-scheduler" [control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler" I0919 16:04:53.467378     197 manifests.go:154] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-scheduler" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml" [etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests" I0919 16:04:53.468431     197 local.go:65] [etcd] wrote Static Pod manifest for a local etcd member to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml" I0919 16:04:53.468470     197 waitcontrolplane.go:83] [wait-control-plane] Waiting for the API server to be healthy I0919 16:04:53.469308     197 loader.go:373] Config loaded from file:  /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf [wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s I0919 16:04:53.471917     197 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://kind-control-plane:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 1 milliseconds I0919 16:04:53.973371     
...
197 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://kind-control-plane:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds [kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy. [kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.
    
    Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
            timed out waiting for the condition
    
    This error is likely caused by:
            - The kubelet is not running
            - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)
    
    If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
            - 'systemctl status kubelet'
            - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'
    
    Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime. To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI. Here is one example how you may list all running Kubernetes containers by using crictl:
            - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
            Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
            - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock logs CONTAINERID' couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init.runWaitControlPlanePhase
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init/waitcontrolplane.go:108 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:259 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:446 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:232 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func1
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:111 github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
            vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:916 github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
            vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1040 github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
            vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:968 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
            cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50 main.main
            cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25 runtime.main
            /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250 runtime.goexit
            /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1598 error execution phase wait-control-plane k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:260 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:446 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:232 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func1
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:111 github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
            vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:916 github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
            vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1040 github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
            vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:968 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
            cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50 main.main
            cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25 runtime.main
            /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250 runtime.goexit
            /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1598  ✗ Starting control-plane ️ Deleted nodes: ["kind-control-plane"] ERROR: failed to create cluster: failed to init node with kubeadm: command "docker exec --privileged kind-control-plane kubeadm init
    --skip-phases=preflight --config=/kind/kubeadm.conf --skip-token-print --v=6" failed with error: exit status 1 Command Output: I0919 16:04:50.065023     197 initconfiguration.go:255] loading configuration from "/kind/kubeadm.conf" W0919 16:04:50.065940     197 initconfiguration.go:332] [config] WARNING: Ignored YAML document with GroupVersionKind kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3, Kind=JoinConfiguration [init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.27.3 I0919 16:04:50.072300     197 certs.go:112] creating a new certificate authority for ca [certs] Using certificateDir folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki" [certs] Generating "ca" certificate and key I0919 16:04:50.164763     197 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for ca certificate [certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key [certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [kind-control-plane kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local localhost] and IPs [10.96.0.1 172.19.0.2 127.0.0.1] [certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key I0919 16:04:50.423042   197 certs.go:112] creating a new certificate authority for front-proxy-ca [certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key I0919 16:04:50.925744     197 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for front-proxy-ca certificate [certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key I0919 16:04:51.241200     197 certs.go:112] creating a new certificate authority for etcd-ca [certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key I0919 16:04:51.475406     197 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for etcd/ca certificate [certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key [certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [kind-control-plane localhost] and IPs [172.19.0.2 127.0.0.1 ::1] [certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key [certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [kind-control-plane localhost] and IPs [172.19.0.2 127.0.0.1 ::1] [certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key [certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key I0919 16:04:51.926244     197 certs.go:78] creating new public/private key files for signing service account users [certs] Generating "sa" key and public key [kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes" I0919 16:04:52.222532     197 kubeconfig.go:103] creating kubeconfig file for admin.conf [kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file I0919 16:04:52.544088     197 kubeconfig.go:103] creating kubeconfig file for kubelet.conf [kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file I0919 16:04:52.836036     197 kubeconfig.go:103] creating kubeconfig file for controller-manager.conf [kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file I0919 16:04:53.045704     197 kubeconfig.go:103] creating kubeconfig file for scheduler.conf [kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file I0919 16:04:53.349922     197 kubelet.go:67] Stopping the kubelet [kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env" [kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml" [kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet [control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests" [control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver" I0919 16:04:53.461569     197 manifests.go:99] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs I0919 16:04:53.462096     197 certs.go:519] validating certificate period for CA certificate I0919 16:04:53.462199     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "ca-certs" for component "kube-apiserver" I0919 16:04:53.462205     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "etc-ca-certificates" for component "kube-apiserver" I0919 16:04:53.462209     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "k8s-certs" for component "kube-apiserver" I0919 16:04:53.462213     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-local-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-apiserver" I0919 16:04:53.462216     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-apiserver" I0919 16:04:53.465579     197 manifests.go:154] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-apiserver" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml" I0919 16:04:53.465626  197 manifests.go:99] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs [control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.465817     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "ca-certs" for component "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.465851     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "etc-ca-certificates" for component "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.465859     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "flexvolume-dir" for component "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.465865     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "k8s-certs" for component "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.465871     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "kubeconfig" for component "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.465877     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-local-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.465883     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-controller-manager" I0919 16:04:53.466516     197 manifests.go:154] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-controller-manager" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml" I0919 16:04:53.466555     197 manifests.go:99] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs I0919 16:04:53.466714     197 manifests.go:125] [control-plane] adding volume "kubeconfig" for component "kube-scheduler" [control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler" I0919 16:04:53.467378     197 manifests.go:154] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-scheduler" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml" [etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests" I0919 16:04:53.468431     197 local.go:65] [etcd] wrote Static Pod manifest for a local etcd member to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml" I0919 16:04:53.468470     197 waitcontrolplane.go:83] [wait-control-plane] Waiting for the API server to be healthy I0919 16:04:53.469308     197 loader.go:373] Config loaded from file:  /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf [wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s I0919 16:04:53.471917     197 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://kind-control-plane:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 1 milliseconds I0919    
...
197 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://kind-control-plane:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds [kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed. [kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy. [kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused. I0919 
...
197 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://kind-control-plane:6443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 0 milliseconds [kubelet-check] It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy. [kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp [::1]:10248: connect: connection refused.
    
    Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
            timed out waiting for the condition
    
    This error is likely caused by:
            - The kubelet is not running
            - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)
    
    If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
            - 'systemctl status kubelet'
            - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'
    
    Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime. To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI. Here is one example how you may list all running Kubernetes containers by using crictl:
            - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
            Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
            - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock logs CONTAINERID' couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init.runWaitControlPlanePhase
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init/waitcontrolplane.go:108 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:259 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:446 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:232 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func1
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:111 github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
            vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:916 github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
            vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1040 github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
            vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:968 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
            cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50 main.main
            cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25 runtime.main
            /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250 runtime.goexit
            /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1598 error execution phase wait-control-plane k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:260 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:446 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:232 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.newCmdInit.func1
            cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:111 github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
            vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:916 github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
            vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:1040 github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
            vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:968 k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
            cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50 main.main
            cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25 runtime.main
            /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:250 runtime.goexit
            /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1598 Stack Trace:  sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/errors.WithStack
            sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/errors/errors.go:59 sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/exec.(*LocalCmd).Run
            sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/exec/local.go:124 sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/cluster/internal/providers/docker.(*nodeCmd).Run
            sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/cluster/internal/providers/docker/node.go:146 sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/exec.CombinedOutputLines
            sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/exec/helpers.go:67 sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/cluster/internal/create/actions/kubeadminit.(*action).Execute
            sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/cluster/internal/create/actions/kubeadminit/init.go:81 sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/cluster/internal/create.Cluster
            sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/cluster/internal/create/create.go:135 sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/cluster.(*Provider).Create
            sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/cluster/provider.go:181 sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/cmd/kind/create/cluster.runE
            sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/cmd/kind/create/cluster/createcluster.go:110 sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/cmd/kind/create/cluster.NewCommand.func1
            sigs.k8s.io/kind/pkg/cmd/kind/create/cluster/createcluster.go:54 github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
            github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.4.0/command.go:856 github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
            github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.4.0/command.go:974 github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
            github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.4.0/command.go:902 sigs.k8s.io/kind/cmd/kind/app.Run
            sigs.k8s.io/kind/cmd/kind/app/main.go:53 sigs.k8s.io/kind/cmd/kind/app.Main
            sigs.k8s.io/kind/cmd/kind/app/main.go:35 main.main
            sigs.k8s.io/kind/main.go:25 runtime.main
            runtime/proc.go:250 runtime.goexit
            runtime/asm_amd64.s:1598
```

To get it to create again I need to reconstruct the container, once reconstructed the create command works successfully

Thanks in advance for any help or advice